# To solve the differential equation use an appropriate change of variables.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, differential

$$2t\left(e^2\right)^y \frac{dy}{dt}=3t^4+\left(e^2\right)^y$$

Please help. I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Is this meant to be $e^{2y}$ or $e^{(2^y)}$?

Comment: @mrtaurho made the correction based on the curly braces in OP's original question

Comment: @mrtaurho  in the orignal question 2y is the exponent of e.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

The obvious one is to first try $u = e^{2y} = \left(e^2\right)^y$ and then $u' = e^{2y}\cdot 2y' = 2uy'$...

Answer (score 2):

$$2t\left(e^2\right)^y \frac{dy}{dt}=3t^4+\left(e^2\right)^y$$
$$t(2e^{2y}y')=3t^4+\left(e^2\right)^y$$
$$t(e^{2y})'-e^{2y}=3t^4$$
Divide by $t^2$ both side
$$\frac {t(e^{2y})'-e^{2y}}{t^2}=3t^2$$
Remember that $(\frac fg)'=\frac {f'g-fg'}{g^2}$
$$(\frac {e^{2y}}{t})'=3t^2$$
Now just integrate both side
$$\frac {e^{2y}}{t}=3\int t^2dt$$

Comment: $\frac{{e^2}^y}{t}=t^3+c$ This is what we ended up with. Is this correct? @Isham

Comment: @TaljanaD yep thats correct

Comment: Then you have that $e^{2y}=t^4+ct$ and take log on both side to get the function y @TaljanaD

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Substitute $u=e^{2y}$ - and therefore $u'=2y'e^{2y}$ - to get an ODE of the form

$$tu'=3t^4+u\Leftrightarrow u'-\frac1t u = 3t^3$$

which can be solved by standard techniques. To be exact first of all solve the homogenous DE $u'-\frac1t u = 0$ which leads to $u= c t$. Variation of constants yields to $c't=3t^3$ therefore $c(t)=t^3+k$ and so finally the solution for $u$ is given by $u=kt+t^4$. Resubstitution leads to $y(t)=\frac12\ln(kt+t^4)$. Everything clear now?

Comment: what happened to the 3?

Comment: @TaljanaD I did not saw it. Fixed it.

Comment: I'm not really sure what to do after that...